# How to connect wxpython with openpyxl?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to use a button to show the information in every cell in a Excel file.

Here's my code, the button has to change between cells to show me the information.

I open the file to see the first cell, but then I can't change the cell. `onG` and `onf` are the buttons to change between cells.

```
    def OnOpen(self,e):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'r')
            sheet_ranget= wb['Tabelle3']

            y = "A" 
            y1 = y + "2" 
            #y2

            #y3
            #y4
            #y5
            #y6
            #y7
            #y8

            Ax = sheet_ranget['A1'].value
            A1 = sheet_ranget[y1].value
            Bx = sheet_ranget['B1'].value
            B1 = sheet_ranget['B2'].value
            Dx = sheet_ranget['D1'].value
            D1 = sheet_ranget['D2'].value
            Ex = sheet_ranget['E1'].value
            E1 = sheet_ranget['E2'].value
            Fx = sheet_ranget['F1'].value
            F1 = sheet_ranget['F2'].value
            Gx = sheet_ranget['G1'].value
            G1 = sheet_ranget['G2'].value
            Hx = sheet_ranget['H1'].value
            H1 = sheet_ranget['H2'].value
            Ix = sheet_ranget['I1'].value
            I1 = sheet_ranget['I2'].value
            #Jx = sheet_ranget['J1'].value
            #J1 = sheet_ranget['J2'].value
            a= "\n\n"
            b= "\t"
            c=":"
            d="Test Case Name"
            e="..."
            f= "NO-"
            g = "*"
            h = "-"
            I = "Theme" 

            #------------------------------------contador inicial
            AA=sheet_ranget['N1'].value
            BB=sheet_ranget['N2'].value
            CC=sheet_ranget['N3'].value
            DD=sheet_ranget['N4'].value
            EE=sheet_ranget['N5'].value
            FF=sheet_ranget['N7'].value
            GG=sheet_ranget['N8'].value
            HH=sheet_ranget['N9'].value
            II=sheet_ranget['N11'].value
            JJ=sheet_ranget['N12'].value
            KK=sheet_ranget['N14'].value
            LL=sheet_ranget['N15'].value

            #---------------------------------------Valores negativos
            AN = sheet_ranget['O4'].value
            BN = sheet_ranget['O5'].value
            CN = sheet_ranget['O7'].value
            DN = sheet_ranget['O8'].value
            EN = sheet_ranget['O9'].value
            FN = sheet_ranget['O11'].value
            GN = sheet_ranget['O12'].value
            HN = sheet_ranget['O14'].value
            IN = sheet_ranget['O15'].value

            #---------------------------------------valores negativos
            self.PQ25I.SetValue(AN)
            self.PQ35I.SetValue(BN)
            self.CTVW250_I.SetValue(IN)
            self.CTVW324_I.SetValue(CN)
            self.CTVW325_I.SetValue(DN)
            self.CTVW361_I.SetValue(EN)

            self.CTVW360_I.SetValue(HN)
            self.CTVW361_II.SetValue(FN)
            self.CTVW411_I.SetValue(GN)

            #---------------------------------------valores positivos
            self.TC.SetValue(AA)
            self.TVC.SetValue(BB)
            self.TIC.SetValue(CC)
            self.P25v.SetValue(DD)
            self.P35v.SetValue(EE)
            self.CTVW250.SetValue(LL)
            self.CTVW324.SetValue(FF)
            self.CTVW325.SetValue(GG)
            self.CTVW361.SetValue(HH)
            self.CTVW360.SetValue(KK)
            self.CTVW361_35.SetValue(II)
            self.CTVW411.SetValue(JJ)

            self.logger.SetValue(Ax+c+b+A1+a+I+c+b+a+D1+a+Ex+a+E1+a+Fx+a+F1+a+Gx+a+G1+a+Hx+a+H1+a+Ix+a+I1)

            #wb.close()
            self.SetTitle(self.filename)
            #bool(sheet_ranget.values)

        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnSave(self,e):
        self.dirname = ""
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save Operation File", self.dirname, "",
        "XML (*.xml)|*.xml| TXT (*.txt)|*.txt|EXCEL (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files (*.*)|*.*", wx.SAVE|wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            itcontains = self.loggerb.GetValue()
            self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            filehandle=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'w')
            filehandle.write(itcontains)
            filehandle.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnSaveN(self,e):
        self.dirname = ""
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save Operation File", self.dirname, "","EXCEL (*.xls)|*.xls*", wx.SAVE|wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            iontains = self.loggerb.GetValue()
            self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            filehandle=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'w')
            filehandle.write(str(iontains))
            filehandle.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        igot = self.doiexit.ShowModal() 
        if igot == wx.ID_YES:
            self.Close(True)

    def OnF(self, event):
          self.logger.Clear()

    def OnG(self, event):
          self.logger.Clear()

view = MyApp
app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()

#self.Show(True)
```